# Trying to get html Dropbox (2 step) working with vba code

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11, dropdownbox

Trying to get a dropbox working from vba code but it seems to have a two-step process before the drop box opens. (Like authentication, the displays a box about the dropbox so you can select and it inserts it into the box. But it is all in the one dropbox, but I think the authentication side is hidden. I can get a basic Dropbox to work with indexes but this one has me stumped. I do not fully understand as fairly new to VBA > HTML side of things.

But my understanding is "SchProgramID" is the authentication or filter code then once it has received that the "TrainerId" will open to give you selected names of which is filtered into a box as you type or you can be selected with a mouse from the list.

I cannot even get focus on either.

Can someone please help me?

The html code from the site is as follows:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TrainerId">Trainor</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">


                            <select class="form-control chosen-select" data-live-search="true" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Trainor must be a number." data-val-required="The Trainor field is required." id="TrainerId" name="TrainerId"><option value="">Select Trainor</option>
<option value="176">Undrico Divina Corpuz Jr.</option>
<option value="204">Domingo Bagadiong Go Jr.</option>
<option value="1200">Marnilo Sayson Sugano </option>
<option value="1238">Dexter Gaoiran Tomas </option>
```

Code I have been playing with

```
'Dim fromSelect, fromSelect1 As HTMLSelectElement
'Dim evt, evt1 As Object
'Set evt = htmlDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
'Set evt1 = htmlDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
'evt.initEvent "change", True, False
'evt1.initEvent "change", True, False
'Set fromSelect = htmlDoc.getElementById("SchProgramId")
'OptionValue = "14526"
'If optionIndex >= 0 Then
'    fromSelect.selectedIndex = OptionValue
'    fromSelect.dispatchEvent evt
'Set fromSelect1 = htmlDoc.getElementById("TrainerId")
'OptionValue = "9570"
If optionIndex >= 0 Then
'    fromSelect.selectedIndex = OptionValue
'    fromSelect.dispatchEvent evt1
end if
```

Comment: Is there an URL you can share? And please share your current code.

Comment: The URL is behind a login on a government site, so I am not willing to advertise that username and login in this environment. Is there a way I can give the URL information privately?

Comment: Can you share the entire page html via pastebin.com? Change the values of any sensitive information. Also, update your question with your code using [edit]. Without your code the question risks getting closed as questions regarding why isn’t this code working should include the relevant code.

Comment: QHarr - Have added the full code to a download link in onedrive > https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmcelN2FJ1nvjCZzaCI7KfXCt3xj

Comment: I need some help understanding the role of SchProgramId. What action do you think is required beyond those I show below please?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on the role of SchProgramId at present.

For showing the dropdown you should be able to use:

```
ie.document.getElementById("TrainerId").Click
```

For selecting elements in the dropdown you should be able to target the `value` attribute by its value e.g. `1421` for the first trainer (or by index)

```
ie.document.querySelector("#TrainerId option[value='1421']").Selected = True
```

Example using index:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#TrainerId").selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: It did nothing. No errors, went straight thru the code but nothing changed on the website. I think the SchProgramId is a part of the query to list the Trainers as it is a live update. I think when the form loads, it looks at this and determines who to list, whether they are current trainers. (I could be wrong on that of course) But When I click the drop box it shows another box and list of all, we shall say current users. I have put 2 screen shots in the same onedrive - https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmcelN2FJ1nvjCWKYwpi0K27KKrK

Comment: Could be. I ran on a static page and the selection worked. If you step through with F8 is the selection made at execution of the pertinent line and then lost?

Comment: I am using IE11 as well

Comment: Have stepped thru with F8 and nothing changed on the website but code showed no errors

Comment: Are you trying to run this code on the correct page? As you had mentioned that this page is behind the login page. But in your code, we can just see that you are trying to finding the element. So did you manage all those things in your code? If possible for you than please provide the detailed page navigation and all the steps which needs to perform before finding the element may help to narrow down the issue.